# Calendar Changed in Swift 3?

Tags: timer, calendar, swift3, xcode8

Hey so I'm working on this little app and I[image]

```
let durationDateComponents = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian).dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: christmasDay, options: [])
```

What do I do here? I get that the error is pointing me to change something with the array, but what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `options`. That's not part of [`dateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar/2293176-datecomponents) and thus the compiler is having trouble identifying the method.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current   // or, if you really need gregorian calendar regardless of the current calendar, `Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)`
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: christmasDay)
```

If you remove `options`, the method is successfully identified and therefore it is able to correctly interpret the expression.